# Can't use cv2.VideoWriter with a timer

Tags: python, opencv

The program should record a 720p video when it detects motion (20fps, 30sec long), and then save it while still showing what the camera currently sees on the screen.

cv2.VideoWriter works properly when I copy code from the [opencv website](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) (bottom of the page), I really don't know where's the issue

```
import os
import cv2
import shutil
import time


def motion():
    filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    output = cv2.VideoWriter(f'{filename}.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (1280, 720))
    start_time = time.time()

    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not capture.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera")
        exit()

    while capture.isOpened():
        # to read frame by frame
        _, img_1 = capture.read()
        _, img_2 = capture.read()
        # find difference between two frames
        diff = cv2.absdiff(img_1, img_2)
        # to convert the frame to grayscale
        diff_gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # apply some blur to smoothen the frame
        diff_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(diff_gray, (5, 5), 0)
        # to get the binary image
        _, thresh_bin = cv2.threshold(diff_blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        # to find contours
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_bin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # to draw the bounding box when the motion is detected
        for contour in contours:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 300:
                cv2.rectangle(img_1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                while int(time.time() - start_time) < 30:
                    frame = cv2.resize(img_1, (1280, 720))
                    output.write(frame)
                    cv2.imshow('Recording...', frame)
                output.release()

        # cv2.drawContours(img_1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # display the output
        show = cv2.resize(img_1, (1360, 768))
        cv2.imshow("Detecting Motion...", show)
        if cv2.waitKey(100) == 13:
            exit()

    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def check_size():
    total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")
    print("Total: %d GiB" % (total // (2 ** 30)))
    print("Used: %d GiB" % (used // (2 ** 30)))
    print("Free: %d GiB" % (free // (2 ** 30)))
    usage = used / total * 100
    return usage


if os.path.exists('/home/adobug/OpenCV'):
    if check_size() > 90:
        # delete some oldest files
        motion()
    else:
        motion()
else:
    os.mkdir('/home/adobug/OpenCV')
    motion()
```

Comment: You're writing the frame repeatedly, one for EVERY contour it finds, and there could be lots.  Did you intend to break the loop after writing the frame once?

Comment: I intend to detect an object, and then write frames continously for 30 sec

Comment: That's not what your loop does.  Your "30 seconds" loop never reads from the camera!  You just repeat the same three lines over and over with the same `img_1` image.  You need a different organization.   If you find motion, you need to remember the start time and then `continue` the loop.  Then, in the main loop, if it is less than 30 seconds since the last motion, you write the frame.

Comment: Soooo I just need a different loop? I don't fully understand sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

The following modification of your code show the captured video, start to record to a video output file when detect movement and finish in 30 seconds. I am not an expert on opencv, probably could be done better.

```
import cv2
import shutil
import time


def motion():
    filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    output = cv2.VideoWriter(f'{filename}.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (1280, 720))
    first_movement = None
    title = 'Recording....'

    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if not capture.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera")
        exit()

    while capture.isOpened():
        # to read frame by frame
        _, img_1 = capture.read()
        _, img_2 = capture.read()
        # find difference between two frames
        diff = cv2.absdiff(img_1, img_2)
        # to convert the frame to grayscale
        diff_gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # apply some blur to smoothen the frame
        diff_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(diff_gray, (5, 5), 0)
        # to get the binary image
        _, thresh_bin = cv2.threshold(diff_blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        # to find contours
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
            thresh_bin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # to draw the bounding box when the motion is detected
        frame = cv2.resize(img_1, (1280, 720))
        win_id = 'CAPTURE'
        for contour in contours:
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 300:
                cv2.rectangle(img_1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                if first_movement is None:
                    # set the time when start to capture
                    print('Staritng capture')
                    title = 'Capturing movement'
                    first_movement = time.time()
            frame = cv2.resize(img_1, (1280, 720))
            output.write(frame)

        if first_movement is not None:
            # check until 30 seconds from the first movement
            elapsed = int(time.time() - first_movement)
            title = 'Cepturing movement %d' % elapsed
            if elapsed > 30:
                break

        cv2.imshow(win_id, frame)
        cv2.setWindowTitle(win_id, title)

        if cv2.waitKey(100) == 13:
            break

    output.release()
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def check_size():
    total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")
    print("Total: %d GiB" % (total // (2 ** 30)))
    print("Used: %d GiB" % (used // (2 ** 30)))
    print("Free: %d GiB" % (free // (2 ** 30)))
    return free // (2 ** 30)


if check_size() > 90:
    motion()
```